# MonoDroid Scaling images in a GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, mono, xamarin.android

I have a GridView which has  a set of ImageViews in it.  I create the Images in the GetView as follows:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null)
    {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes  
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(118, 132); // images are all the same dimension
        imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitXy);
        imageView.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
    }

    imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images  
int[] thumbIds =
{  
    Resource.Drawable.IconAdvocacy, Resource.Drawable.IconBusinessServices,  
    Resource.Drawable.IconContactUs, Resource.Drawable.IconDistrict,  
    Resource.Drawable.IconEvents, Resource.Drawable.IconFind,  
    Resource.Drawable.IconLawsRegs, Resource.Drawable.IconHealth,  
    Resource.Drawable.IconPracMgmt, Resource.Drawable.IconPublications,  
    Resource.Drawable.IconUpdates, Resource.Drawable.IconUploadPhoto
};
```

As you can see I have a fixed size defined in the LayoutParams function.  This causes the images to be the same size on every device.

Question: What is the best way to scale the images?

Should I:
  1) Simply create images at different sizes in each of the drawable, -hdpi, -ldpi, and -mdpi folders?  If so, how do I specify the size to LayoutParams?

2) Get the DisplayMetrics?  If so, how do I do that?  I have been unable to get MonoDroid info on how to do this.  The examples in the documentation do not seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think since you have a fixed number of images and you are not dynamically loading them, it is probably safe enough to just create the resources that you need ahead of time like how you have specified in Option 1. If you ever need to load dynamically or size images on the fly, then I might recommend going down the Option 2 path.

**Option 1**

In order to get images for all layouts, you can specify the -land (landscape) and -port (portrait) extension to the dpi extensions. So, for example, you can have drawable-mdpi-port and drawable-mdpi-land. For a full listing of options and some more detailed info, see take a look at the [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) documentation.

**Option 2**

This code should work out well for getting the current display density through code. If you are calling it from an activity, this should work outright. If you are calling from a fragment or whatnot, make sure to reference the Activity first.

```csh
var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
switch (metrics.DensityDpi)
{
    case DisplayMetricsDensity.Default:
        break;
    case DisplayMetricsDensity.High:
        break;
    case DisplayMetricsDensity.Low:
        break;
    case DisplayMetricsDensity.Xhigh:
        break;
}
```